# JWT based authentication for web app and native android app

Tags: android, rest, cookies, jwt

I've a back-end server implementing JWT based authentication for REST APIs. While the front-end webapp is developed in angular js and I am planning to store JWT in HTTPOnly cookie ( with CSRF protection ). These REST APIs are also being accessed by a native android app. However, it looks like native android app can not set cookies. I would like to avoid storing JWT in browser local storage.

Is there a common and secure way to implement JWT based authentication for a REST APIs which works for for both a web app and a native android mobile app?

Earlier I thought of using USER-AGENT to distinguish between webapp and mobile app and implement two different auth mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you do as the protocol (OAuth 2.0), you only send the token to the user using a fragment, a query string or a form post (depending on the client preference) not a cookie!
How they store the token is up to them.
Once you send something to a public client there is nowhere safe to save anything. you better put the token in local storage or session storage rather than cookies which may lead to CSRF attacks. Access_Token is short-lived and its leakage should not be harmful.